# Pull to refresh causes question content to disappear and force close

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

In version 0.1.7 of the Stack Exchange app, if I pull down to refresh on a question, the body of the question becomes "null", the number of votes goes to zero, asked changes to Dec 31, 1969 and the user changes to "unknown".

Also, if I pull to refresh on the answers screen, it causes a force close most of the time.

[image]

Comment: Is this happening everytime you pull-to-refresh a question, or just once in a while?

Comment: Yes its happening every time I do pull-to-refresh a question and also crashes app if I do pull-to-refresh after it.

Comment: Ah, it just happened to me as well. Looking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a logic bug when choosing [api filters](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters), causing the question to be loaded without content. This was introduced in 0.1.7 and will be fixed in 0.1.8, which I'll push to Google Play right now (in my experience, it should be available within 1-2 hours).