# Unknown user displayed on answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, android-app

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192996/pull-to-refresh-causes-question-content-to-disappear-and-force-close) mentions an unknown user, and was marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). However, I still got it today, after the 0.1.10 update:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely at the [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48241/windows-7-laptop-unable-to-recognize-samsung-gt-s7562-and-micrommax-a116-android) on the web, that answer indeed doesn't have an owner (anymore), that's why we display "unknown".

(The strange badge counts are obviously wrong though; I've fixed that for 0.1.11)

Comment: Why not "anonymous" and in gray, like on the regular site?

Comment: It _does_ have an owner. They just don't have an account there.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd it's not Anonymous. The name is "Dan". That's called not having an account there.

Comment: @Cole right, so still wonder why "unknown" and not "Dan" and gray. Maybe it's because this data is not exposed via the API?

Comment: Out of curiosity what does (Yahoo) mean as seen here http://superuser.com/questions/80556/how-do-you-view-all-threads-running-on-linux?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: @Celeritas In ancient times, the default display name for users who hadn't changed their username was "unknown (Yahoo)" or "unkown (Google)" or whatever service they logged in with. For a long time now this isn't the case anymore; the default name instead is "user12345", where 12345 is the user id. The only place where you still see those is questions/answers from users who were deleted before that change, where we recorded the last existing user name as the name to be displayed on the question (note that the one you have there is a very old question).