# Unknown User in Community Wiki

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, community-wiki

The answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193317/unknown-user-displayed-on-answer) says that the user was unknown because (s)he does not have an account anymore.

The comments under that says the post is not marked anonymous because it has an owner who does not have an account there.

1. If someone posts a question in a site they don't have an account will his/her profile be viewable when the unknown user is clicked? Will the question be still linked to the user though (s)he does not have an account in that site?
2. The answer in the picture below is posted by an active [meta user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/22164/thetxi). Why is the post marked unknown user? 
   [image]

Edit:

1. I checked the linked post, but there seems to be no conclusive answer. I want official clarification.
2. Please check the first question about unknown user.

Comment: 54% of the changes are by unknown users - did you look at the revisions? Not sure where you think the bug is.

Comment: The user listed on a community wiki is **not** the author of the post, but the person who has contributed the most to the post. In that case, the most contributions came from unknown users.

Comment: Ah, that answers the second question. So unknown user under a community wiki would be the person who contributed the most to the post and not the OP. Thanks @animuson

Comment: @Oded the error was due to misunderstanding. I thought the OP's name would appear under community wiki.

Comment: @shadowWizard what about the first question? Is that also a duplicate? Also the answer in the question linked seems to be incomplete?